# Cannot obtain a mutable reference when iterating a recursive structure: cannot borrow as mutable more than once at a time

Tags: rust, mutable, borrowing

I'm trying to navigate a recursive data structure iteratively in order to insert elements at a certain position. To my limited understanding, this means taking a mutable reference to the root of the structure and successively replacing it by a reference to its follower:

```
type Link = Option<Box<Node>>;

struct Node {
    next: Link
}

struct Recursive {
    root: Link
}

impl Recursive {
    fn back(&mut self) -> &mut Link {
        let mut anchor = &mut self.root;
        while let Some(ref mut node) = *anchor {
            anchor = &mut node.next;
        }
        anchor
    }
}
```

[(Rust playground link)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=119706859a0013c7f11dd8ad9c284386&version=stable&backtrace=0)

However, this fails:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `anchor.0` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:14:24
   |
14 |         while let Some(ref mut node) = *anchor {
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                        |
   |                        second mutable borrow occurs here
   |                        first mutable borrow occurs here
...
18 |     }
   |     - first borrow ends here

error[E0506]: cannot assign to `anchor` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:15:13
   |
14 |         while let Some(ref mut node) = *anchor {
   |                        ------------ borrow of `anchor` occurs here
15 |             anchor = &mut node.next;
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ assignment to borrowed `anchor` occurs here

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*anchor` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:17:9
   |
14 |         while let Some(ref mut node) = *anchor {
   |                        ------------ first mutable borrow occurs here
...
17 |         anchor
   |         ^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
18 |     }
   |     - first borrow ends here
```

This makes sense as both `anchor` and `node` refer to the same structure, but I actually don't care about `anchor` any more after destructuring it.

How could `back()` be implemented correctly using safe Rust?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is possible... but I wish I had a more elegant solution.

The trick is NOT to borrow from `anchor`, and therefore to juggle between two accumulators:

- one holding the reference to the current node
- the other being assigned the reference to the next node

This leads me to:

```
impl Recursive {
    fn back(&mut self) -> &mut Link {
        let mut anchor = &mut self.root;

        loop {
            let tmp = anchor;
            if let Some(ref mut node) = *tmp {
                anchor = &mut node.next;
            } else {
                anchor = tmp;
                break;
            }
        }

        anchor
    }
}
```

Not exactly pretty, but this is something the borrow checker can get behind so ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

@ker has improved on this by creating an unnamed temporary:

```
impl Recursive {
    fn back(&mut self) -> &mut Link {
        let mut anchor = &mut self.root;

        loop {
            match {anchor} {
                &mut Some(ref mut node) => anchor = &mut node.next,
                other => return other,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The trick here is that using `{anchor}` *moves* the content of `anchor` into an unnamed temporary on which the match executes. Therefore, in the `match` block we are not borrowing from `anchor` but from the temporary, leaving us free to modify `anchor`. See the related blog post [Stuff the Identity Function Does (in Rust)](https://bluss.github.io/rust/fun/2015/10/11/stuff-the-identity-function-does/).

Comment: Awesome! Just so that I understand what's happening here: 1) `anchor` has the initial reference 2) `tmp` is moved from `anchor`, which means that `anchor` ist not a reference any more 3) `tmp` can be safely borrowed from as it is dropped as soon as the loop iteration ends

Comment: The most awesome, here, is that I initially forgot the `anchor = tmp;` in the `else` branch and rustc raised an error for it... anyway, yes the idea is that you cannot re-assign `anchor` while it is borrowed, so we transfer the reference to `tmp` and then borrow `tmp` to assign `anchor`.

Comment: This can actually be written pretty concisely because we can call `is_some()` on `anchor` before moving it. I've edited your post.

Comment: Here's a version of your solution without temporaries or unwrap: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2018fad3cac6c2fd9bdf62e211433ee6&version=stable&backtrace=0

Comment: @FabianKnorr: I don't like using `unwrap` where I can avoid it, because while it is safe, it's also a source of (potential) crash.

Comment: As of Oct/2020, the `&mut` in front of `Some` (in the second version) is not needed. Was it ever needed and/or does it have some illustrative purpose?

Comment: @Marcus: It was needed before [Match Ergonomics](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2005-match-ergonomics.md) was implemented. It's still valid, because that's what _really_ happens behind the scenes.

Answer (score 13):

The original code works as-is once [non-lexical lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50251487/155423) are enabled:

```
type Link = Option<Box<Node>>;

struct Node {
    next: Link,
}

struct Recursive {
    root: Link,
}

impl Recursive {
    fn back(&mut self) -> &mut Link {
        let mut anchor = &mut self.root;
        while let Some(node) = anchor {
            anchor = &mut node.next;
        }
        anchor
    }
}
```

Non-lexical lifetimes increases the precision of the compiler's borrow checker, allowing it to see that the mutable borrow of `anchor` is no longer used. We can also simplify the keywords in the `if let` due to recent language changes.

Answer (score 7):

You can use recursion to satisfy the borrow checker. This has the disadvantage of creating a stack frame for every item in your list. If your list is long, this will definitely run into a stack overflow. LLVM will optimize the `Node::back` method into a loop (see the LLVM IR generated on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=eed22f0922b5d137e44b5eb4c1685ff1&version=nightly&backtrace=0))

```
impl Node {
    fn back(&mut self) -> &mut Link {
        match self.next {
            Some(ref mut node) => node.back(),
            None => &mut self.next,
        }
    }
}

impl Recursive {
    fn back(&mut self) -> Option<&mut Link> {
        self.root.as_mut().map(|node| node.back())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It works:

```
fn back(&mut self) -> &mut Link {
    let mut anchor = &mut self.root;
    while anchor.is_some(){
        anchor = &mut {anchor}.as_mut().unwrap().next;
    }
    anchor
}
```