# Changing mutable reference in a loop

Tags: rust, nodes, trie, borrow-checker

I'm trying to implement a recursive insertion on a trie but got stuck with the error: "cannot assign to `cur_node` because it is borrowed", "cannot borrow `*cur_node` as mutable more than once at a time".

```
pub trait Trie {
    fn insert_word(&mut self, word: &str);
}

pub struct VectorTrie {
    edges: Vec<Edge>,
}

pub struct Edge {
    ch: char,
    to: VectorTrie,
}

impl Trie for VectorTrie {
    fn insert_word(&mut self, word: &str) {
        let mut cur_node = self;
        for ch in word.chars() {
            cur_node = cur_node.get_or_create(ch);
        }
    }
}

impl VectorTrie {
    pub fn get_or_create(&mut self, ch: char) -> &mut VectorTrie {
        match self.edges.binary_search_by(|e| e.ch.cmp(&ch)) {
            Ok(idx) => &mut self.edges[idx].to,
            Err(idx) => {
                let to = VectorTrie { edges: Vec::new() };
                let e = Edge { ch: ch, to: to };
                self.edges.insert(idx, e);
                &mut self.edges[idx].to
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, what I wanted to do is just to recursively insert the individual characters in a word by taking the `Node("VectorTrie")` returned by each insertion and continuing to insert the next character to that `Node`.

No doubt the error is again because I tried to apply C logic to Rust... I'm trying to create the `cur_node` variable as a temporary reference, modifiable on each loop, though apparently this is not happening here. What should be the idiomatic way to achieve my aim in Rust then?

Comment: What prevents your code from having mutable aliases, which is [forbidden in safe Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/references-and-borrowing.html#the-rules)?

Comment: @Shepmaster Sorry, forgot to include that. Was in another file. It currently just contains a function definition. I now included it.

Comment: Are you ready for some deep magic? [This works](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=4638635a652364baf0d30038c932d315&version=stable). You can find an explanation on the [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37986640/155423).