# Adding an append method to a singly linked list

Tags: rust

I was looking through the [singly linked list example on rustbyexample.com](http://rustbyexample.com/custom_types/enum/testcase_linked_list.html) and I noticed the implementation had no `append` method, so I decided to try and implement it:

```
fn append(self, elem: u32) -> List {
    let mut node = &self;
    loop { 
        match *node {
            Cons(_, ref tail) => {
                node = tail;
            },
            Nil => {
                node.prepend(elem);
                break;
            },
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

The above is one of many different attempts, but I cannot seem to find a way to iterate down to the tail and modify it, then somehow return the head, without upsetting the borrow checker in some way.

I am trying to figure out a solution that doesn't involve copying data or doing additional bookkeeping outside the `append` method.

Comment: Have you tried a recursive approach? It's more natural here (although it'll run into stack-overflow issues with large lists).

Comment: @MatthieuM. yeah, I know. My first implementation was recursive and it sort of worked except it returned the tail of the list and the nodes before it became inaccessible. I switched to an iterative approach so I could have more control if I needed.

Comment: Note that `return self;` should just be `self`. Clippy will warn you about things like that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As described in [Cannot obtain a mutable reference when iterating a recursive structure: cannot borrow as mutable more than once at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37986640/155423), you need to transfer ownership of the mutable reference when performing iteration. This is needed to ensure you never have two mutable references to the same thing.

We use similar code as that Q&A to get a mutable reference to the last item (`back`) which will always be the `Nil` variant. We then call it and set that `Nil` item to a `Cons`. We wrap all that with a by-value function because that's what the API wants.

No extra allocation, no risk of running out of stack frames.

```
use List::*;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum List {
    Cons(u32, Box<List>),
    Nil,
}

impl List {
    fn back(&mut self) -> &mut List {
        let mut node = self;

        loop {
            match {node} {
                &mut Cons(_, ref mut next) => node = next,
                other => return other,
            }
        }
    }

    fn append_ref(&mut self, elem: u32) {        
        *self.back() = Cons(elem, Box::new(Nil));
    }

    fn append(mut self, elem: u32) -> Self {
        self.append_ref(elem);
        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let n = Nil;
    let n = n.append(1);
    println!("{:?}", n);
    let n = n.append(2);
    println!("{:?}", n);
    let n = n.append(3);
    println!("{:?}", n);
}
```

---

When [non-lexical lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251487/what-are-non-lexical-lifetimes) are enabled, this function can be more obvious:

```
fn back(&mut self) -> &mut List {
    let mut node = self;

    while let Cons(_, next) = node {
        node = next;
    }

    node
}
```

Comment: I like this answer much more than mine (I gave it a shot), I couldn't figure out how to implement something like `back`, the temp variable was the key!

Comment: Is it intended that `match {node}` behave differently than `match node`, which doesn't compile? I never would have thought to use the former.

Comment: @user4815162342 yes. As described in [Obtaining a mutable reference by iterating a recursive structure](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37986640/155423), you need to transfer ownership of the mutable reference when performing iteration.

Comment: I see, using `match node` performs a simple borrow, while `match {node}` forces a move.

Answer (score 2):

So, it's actually going to be slightly more difficult than you may think; mostly because `Box` is *really* missing a destructive `take` method which would return its content.

---

**Easy way: the recursive way, no return.**

```
fn append_rec(&mut self, elem: u32) {
    match *self {
        Cons(_, ref mut tail) => tail.append_rec(elem),
        Nil => *self = Cons(elem, Box::new(Nil)),
    }
}
```

This is relatively easy, as mentioned.

---

**Harder way: the recursive way, with return.**

```
fn append_rec(self, elem: u32) -> List {
    match self {
        Cons(e, tail) => Cons(e, Box::new((*tail).append_rec(elem))),
        Nil => Cons(elem, Box::new(Nil)),
    }
}
```

Note that this is *grossly* inefficient. For a list of size N, we are destroying N boxes *and* allocating N new ones. In place mutation (the first approach), was *much* better in this regard.

---

**Harder way: the iterative way, with no return.**

```
fn append_iter_mut(&mut self, elem: u32) {
    let mut current = self;
    loop {
        match {current} {
            &mut Cons(_, ref mut tail) => current = tail,
            c @ &mut Nil => {
                *c = Cons(elem, Box::new(Nil));
                return;
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Okay... so iterating (mutably) over a nested data structure is not THAT easy because ownership and borrow-checking will ensure that:

- a mutable reference is never copied, only moved,
- a mutable reference with an outstanding borrow cannot be modified.

This is why here:

- we use `{current}` to move `current` into the match,
- we use `c @ &mut Nil` because we need a to name the match of `&mut Nil` since `current` has been moved.

Note that thankfully rustc is smart enough to check the execution path and detect that it's okay to continue looping as long as we take the `Cons` branch since we reinitialize `current` in that branch, however it's not okay to continue after taking the `Nil` branch, which forces us to terminate the loop :)

---

**Harder way: the iterative way, with return**

```
fn append_iter(self, elem: u32) -> List {
    let mut stack = List::default();
    {
        let mut current = self;
        while let Cons(elem, tail) = current {
            stack = stack.prepend(elem);
            current = take(tail);
        }
    }

    let mut result = List::new();
    result = result.prepend(elem);

    while let Cons(elem, tail) = stack {
        result = result.prepend(elem);
        stack = take(tail);
    }

    result
}
```

In the recursive way, we were using the stack to keep the items for us, here we use a stack structure instead.

It's even more inefficient than the recursive way with return was; each node cause *two* deallocations and *two* allocations.

---

**TL;DR**: in-place modifications are generally more efficient, don't be afraid of using them when necessary.

Comment: *`Box` is really missing a destructive take* — it's `*boxed_thing`

Comment: @Shepmaster: Which trait does that map to? Or is it another box-specific magic?

Comment: Sadly, it's box-specific magic. I think that the hypothetical [`DerefMove` and friends](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/997) would extend it to other types.

Comment: @Shepmaster: Damned, I searched for it a couple time and I can't find any mention of it in the documentation of `Box`. I couldn't understand how people were doing without it (it's just that useful).

Answer (score 1):

As the `len` method is implemented recursively, I have done the same for the `append` implementation:

```
fn append(self, elem: u32) -> List {
    match self {
        Cons(current_elem, tail_box) => {
            let tail = *tail_box;
            let new_tail = tail.append(elem);

            new_tail.prepend(current_elem)
        }
        Nil => {
            List::new().prepend(elem)
        }
    }
}
```

One possible iterative solution would be to implement `append` in terms of `prepend` and a reverse function, like so (it won't be as performant but should still only be O(N)):

```
// Reverses the list
fn rev(self) -> List {
    let mut result = List::new();
    let mut current = self;
    while let Cons(elem, tail) = current {
        result = result.prepend(elem);
        current = *tail;
    }

    result
}

fn append(self, elem: u32) -> List {
    self.rev().prepend(elem).rev()
}
```