# How to clone a Box<CustomStruct> when I keep getting "no method named clone"?

Tags: rust

I want to clone `head` which is a `Box<Node<T>>`:

```rust
let mut node = Some((*head).clone());
```

Here is the full code ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b6d1378cca1608335a84924bc6529124)):

```rust
use std::boxed::Box;

pub struct List<T> {
    pub head: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
    pub size: u64,
}

impl<T> List<T> {
    pub fn new() -> List<T> {
        return List {
            head: Option::None,
            size: 0,
        };
    }

    pub fn push_back(&mut self, data: T) {
        match &self.head {
            Some(head) => {
                let mut node = Some((*head).clone());
                while (*(node).unwrap()).next.is_some() {
                    node = (*node.unwrap()).next;
                }
                node.unwrap().next = Some(Box::new(Node::new(data)));
            }
            None => {
                self.head = Some(Box::new(Node::new(data)));
            }
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Node<T> {
    pub next: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
    pub value: T,
}

impl<T> Node<T> {
    pub fn new(v: T) -> Node<T> {
        Node {
            next: Option::None,
            value: v,
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler keeps saying the method `clone` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `clone` found for type `std::boxed::Box<Node<T>>` in the current scope
  --> src/lib.rs:19:45
   |
19 |                 let mut node = Some((*head).clone());
   |                                             ^^^^^
   |
   = note: the method `clone` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `Node<T> : std::clone::Clone`
           `std::boxed::Box<Node<T>> : std::clone::Clone`
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
   = note: the following trait defines an item `clone`, perhaps you need to implement it:
           candidate #1: `std::clone::Clone`
```

I tried to add `#[derive(Clone)]` but it still doesn't work:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Node<T> {
    pub next: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
    pub value: T
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A reproduction of the error:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Node<T> {
    pub next: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
    pub value: T,
}

fn thing<T>(node: Node<T>) {
    node.clone();
}
```

```
error[E0599]: no method named `clone` found for type `Node<T>` in the current scope
 --> src/lib.rs:8:10
  |
2 | pub struct Node<T> {
  | ------------------ method `clone` not found for this
...
8 |     node.clone();
  |          ^^^^^
  |
  = note: the method `clone` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
          `Node<T> : std::clone::Clone`
  = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
  = note: the following trait defines an item `clone`, perhaps you need to implement it:
          candidate #1: `std::clone::Clone`
```

You need to add a trait bound that says that `T` implements `Clone`:

```
fn thing<T>(node: Node<T>)
where
    T: Clone,
{
    node.clone();
}
```

See also:

- [Deriving a trait results in unexpected compiler error, but the manual implementation works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39415052/155423)

---

Your code has numerous non-idiomatic aspects:

- unneeded import of `std::boxed::Box`
- unneeded `unwrap`s
- unneeded dereferences.

You don't even need clone here, and it's probably incorrect to use it. I'd write:

```
pub fn push_back(&mut self, data: T)
where
    T: Clone,
{
    let spot = match &mut self.head {
        Some(head) => {
            let mut node = &mut head.next;
            while let Some(n) = node {
                node = &mut n.next;
            }
            node
        }
        None => &mut self.head,
    };

    *spot = Some(Box::new(Node::new(data)));
}
```

See also:

- [Adding an append method to a singly linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43976787/155423)