# Update a mutable reference in a loop

Tags: rust

This is an example that doesn't work:

```
fn main() {
    struct Node {
        children: Vec<Node>,
    }
    impl Node {
        fn new() -> Node {
            Node {
                children: Vec::new(),
            }
        }
    }

    let mut node = Node::new();
    node.children.push(Node::new());

    let mut x = &mut node;
    loop {
        x = &mut x.children[0];
    }
}
```

Running this, I get an error of:

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `x` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:18:9
   |
18 |         x = &mut x.children[0];
   |         ^^^^^^^^^----------^^^
   |         |        |
   |         |        borrow of `x` occurs here
   |         assignment to borrowed `x` occurs here

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `x.children` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:18:18
   |
18 |         x = &mut x.children[0];
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow starts here in previous iteration of loop
19 |     }
20 | }
   | - mutable borrow ends here
```

Is there any way to update `x` to a mutable reference of one of `x`'s child nodes without re-borrowing `x`?

Comment: Relevant: [Obtaining a mutable reference by iterating a recursive structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37987197/2731452)

Comment: See also [this example](https://github.com/nikomatsakis/nll-rfc/blob/master/0000-nonlexical-lifetimes.md#problem-case-4-mutating-mut-references) in the RFC for non-lexical lifetimes.  Your code just works with NLLs enabled ([playgorund](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=758460768747fffc359ece9747c6ab4e&version=nightly)).

Comment: @SvenMarnach wow thanks! This is *exactly* what I was looking for!!