# Iterating through a recursive structure using mutable references and returning the last valid reference

Tags: reference, rust, mutable, borrowing

I'm trying to recurse down a structure of nodes, modifying them, and then returning the last `Node` that I get to. I solved the problems with mutable references in the loop using an [example in the non-lexical lifetimes RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2094-nll.md#problem-case-4-mutating-mut-references). If I try to return the mutable reference to the last `Node`, I get a `use of moved value` error:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node {
    children: Vec<Node>,
}

impl Node {
    fn new(children: Vec<Self>) -> Self {
        Self { children }
    }
    fn get_last(&mut self) -> Option<&mut Node> {
        self.children.last_mut()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut root = Node::new(vec![Node::new(vec![])]);

    let current = &mut root;

    println!("Final: {:?}", get_last(current));
}


fn get_last(mut current: &mut Node) -> &mut Node {
    loop {
        let temp = current;
        println!("{:?}", temp);

        match temp.get_last() {
            Some(child) => { current = child },
            None => break,
        }
    }

    current
}
```

Gives this error

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `*current`
  --> test.rs:51:5
   |
40 |         let temp = current;
   |             ---- value moved here
...
51 |     current
   |     ^^^^^^^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `current` has type `&mut Node`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

If I return the temporary value instead of breaking, I get the error `cannot borrow as mutable more than once`.

```
fn get_last(mut current: &mut Node) -> &mut Node {
    loop {
        let temp = current;
        println!("{:?}", temp);

        match temp.get_last() {
            Some(child) => { current = child },
            None => return temp,
        }
    }
}
```

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*temp` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> test.rs:47:28
   |
43 |         match temp.get_last() {
   |               ---- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
47 |             None => return temp,
   |                            ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
48 |         }
49 |     }
   |     - first borrow ends here
```

How can I iterate through the structure with mutable references and return the last `Node`? I've searched, but I haven't found any solutions for this specific problem.

I can't use [Obtaining a mutable reference by iterating a recursive structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986640/obtaining-a-mutable-reference-by-iterating-a-recursive-structure) because it gives me a borrowing more than once error:

```
fn get_last(mut current: &mut Node) -> &mut Node {
    loop {
        let temp = current;
        println!("{:?}", temp);

        match temp.get_last() {
            Some(child) => current = child,
            None => current = temp,
        }
    }
    current
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is indeed different from [Cannot obtain a mutable reference when iterating a recursive structure: cannot borrow as mutable more than once at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37986640/155423). If we look at the answer there, modified a bit, we can see that it matches on a value and is able to return the value that was matched on in the terminal case. That is, the return value is an `Option`:

```
fn back(&mut self) -> &mut Option<Box<Node>> {
    let mut anchor = &mut self.root;

    loop {
        match {anchor} {
            &mut Some(ref mut node) => anchor = &mut node.next,
            other => return other, // transferred ownership to here
        }
    }
}
```

Your case is complicated by two aspects:

1. The lack of [non-lexical lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50251487/155423).
2. The fact that you want to take a mutable reference and "give it up" in one case (there are children) and not in the other (no children). This is conceptually the same as this:

   ```
   fn maybe_identity<T>(_: T) -> Option<T> { None }

   fn main() {
       let name = String::from("vivian");

       match maybe_identity(name) {
           Some(x) => println!("{}", x),
           None => println!("{}", name),
       }
   }
   ```

   The compiler cannot tell that the `None` case could (*very* theoretically) continue to use `name`.

The straight-forward solution is to encode this "get it back" action explicitly. We create an enum that returns the `&mut self` in the case of no children, a helper method that returns that enum, and rewrite the primary method to use the helper:

```
enum LastOrNot<'a> {
    Last(&'a mut Node),
    NotLast(&'a mut Node),
}

impl Node {
    fn get_last_or_self(&mut self) -> LastOrNot<'_> {
        match self.children.is_empty() {
            false => LastOrNot::Last(self.children.last_mut().unwrap()),
            true => LastOrNot::NotLast(self),
        }
    }

    fn get_last(mut current: &mut Node) -> &mut Node {
        loop {
            match { current }.get_last_or_self() {
                LastOrNot::Last(child) => current = child,
                LastOrNot::NotLast(end) => return end,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that we are using all of the techniques exposed in both [Returning a reference from a HashMap or Vec causes a borrow to last beyond the scope it's in?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38023871/155423) and [Cannot obtain a mutable reference when iterating a recursive structure: cannot borrow as mutable more than once at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37986640/155423).

---

With an in-progress [reimplementation of NLL](https://github.com/rust-lang/polonius), we can simplify `get_last_or_self` a bit to avoid the boolean:

```
fn get_last_or_self(&mut self) -> LastOrNot<'_> {
    match self.children.last_mut() {
        Some(l) => LastOrNot::Last(l),
        None => LastOrNot::NotLast(self),
    }
}
```

The final version of Polonius should allow reducing the entire problem to a *very* simple form:

```
fn get_last(mut current: &mut Node) -> &mut Node {
    while let Some(child) = current.get_last() {
        current = child;
    }

    current
}
```

See also:

- [Returning a reference from a HashMap or Vec causes a borrow to last beyond the scope it's in?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38023871/155423)
- [Cannot obtain a mutable reference when iterating a recursive structure: cannot borrow as mutable more than once at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37986640/155423)

Comment: The final, most concise version of `get_last` works now with `-Z polonius` (on 1.44 nightly).