# How can I pattern match a tuple containing a &mut enum and use the enum in one match arm and a recursive call in another?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching, borrow-checker

How can the code below be made to compile? It seems perfectly safe, but I can't convince the compiler that it is.

The version matching `*self` gives the error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
 --> src/main.rs:8:16
  |
8 |         match (*self, y) {
  |                ^^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

The version matching `self` gives:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `*self`
  --> src/main.rs:17:26
   |
8  |         match (self, y) {
   |                ---- value moved here
...
17 |                 (*a * b, self)
   |                          ^^^^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `self` has type `&'a mut Foo<'a>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

```
enum Foo<'a> {
    Foo1(Option<&'a mut Foo<'a>>),
    Foo2(i16),
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn bar(&'a mut self, y: i16) -> (i16, &'a mut Foo<'a>) {
        match (self, y) {
            (&mut Foo::Foo1(Some(ref mut a)), b) if (b == 5) => {
                return a.bar(y)
            },

            (&mut Foo::Foo2(ref mut a), b) if (b == 5) => {
                print!("is five");
                *a = (b + 42) as i16;

                (*a * b, self)
            },

            ref mut x => {
                print!("is not five!");
                (y, self)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I feel like I would need a match arm such as the following, but it doesn't seem to be valid syntax:

```
(ref mut f @ Foo::Foo1, b) if (b == 5) => {
    print!("is five");
    f.0 = b + 42;
    (b, f)
}
```

```
error[E0532]: expected unit struct/variant or constant, found tuple variant `Foo::Foo1`
  --> src/main.rs:24:30
   |
24 |                 (ref mut f @ Foo::Foo1, b) if (b == 5) => {
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^ not a unit struct/variant or constant
```

This is a dumbed down version of a `deep_fetch_mut` of a `toml::Value` that I am trying to write. The goal would be to be able to call `.deep_fetch_mut(vec!["aaa","bbb","ccc"])`, that will return a mutable reference to that value inside the `toml::Value`.

This question is an extension of [How can I pattern match a tuple containing a &mut enum and use the enum in the match arm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51329458/how-can-i-pattern-match-a-tuple-containing-a-mut-enum-and-use-the-enum-in-the-m)

Comment: Again, returning `self` seemingly serves no purpose.

Comment: But it does, because when calling it with `Foo::Foo1(Foo::Foo1(Foo::Foo1(Foo::Foo2(5)))`, the returned reference is to `Foo:Foo2(5)`, not the original reference passed in. The whole point is to search for that element in the data structure.

Comment: Adjusting the solution in the other question for the second and third arm, with an early return in the first is not working here: `cannot borrow *self as mutable more than once at a time`

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [Iterating through a recursive structure using mutable references and returning the last valid reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48610593/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to compile, but it's very ugly. Is there a way to simplify this?

```
enum Foo<'a> {
    Foo1(Option<&'a mut Foo<'a>>),
    Foo2(i16),
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn bar(&'a mut self, y: i16) -> (i16, &'a mut Foo<'a>) {
        match (&mut *self, y) {
            (Foo::Foo1(Some(ref mut a)), b) if (b == 5) => {
                return a.bar(y)
            },

            (self2, c) => {
                let n = match (&mut *self2 , c) {
                    (Foo::Foo2(ref mut a), b) if (b == 5) => {
                        print!("is five");
                        *a = (b + 42) as i16;

                        *a * b
                    },

                    ref mut x => {
                        print!("is not five!");
                        y
                    }
                };

                return (n, self2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```