# How to copy a raw pointer when implementing a linked list in Rust?

Tags: rust

I am writing a recursive type `ListNode` in Rust. I have to use `Box` in the struct and I am trying to write a loop to add `next` `ListNode`. However, I would like to try using a pointer except recursive method.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct ListNode {
    val: i32,
    next: Option<Box<ListNode>>,
}

impl ListNode {
    fn new(i: i32) -> Self {
        ListNode { val: i, next: None }
    }

    fn add_l(&mut self, l: &Vec<i32>) {
        let mut p: *mut ListNode = self as *mut ListNode;
        for i in l {
            unsafe {
                (*p).next = Some(Box::new(ListNode::new(*i)));
                let temp_b = Box::from_raw(p);
                p = Box::into_raw(temp_b.next.wrap());
            };
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = ListNode::new(1);
    a.add_l(&vec![2, 3, 4, 5]);
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

I found that `a` is changed to the last `NodeList` with the `val` of 5:

```
ListNode { val: 5, next: None }
```

1. Is there any way I can copy a pointer so I can keep `a` stable?
2. If there is no way I can copy pointer, how can I implement this?

Comment: *I would like to try using a pointer* — one of the biggest reasons to use Rust is to **avoid** using pointers when possible.

Comment: The first time you hit that `Box::from_raw`, the pointer you pass it is not derived from a `Box`. I'm pretty confused by what you're trying to do here and I don't understand what it has to do with copying a pointer. [Raw pointers are trivially copyable](http://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=64eddadd117c9fd9c9f8b0167b154cb2&version=stable&mode=debug).

Comment: If I do not create `temp_b` to keep pointer, `p = Box::into_raw((*p).next.unwrap());` will give me `cannot move out of dereference of raw pointer` error when I am compiling

Comment: Obligatory link to [*Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists*](http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/) :) Chapter 6 onwards demonstrates how to write a data structure using `unsafe`. Although I'll second what Shepmaster and Doug said - you're probably better off sticking with `Rc` (which is what the earlier chapters show you how to do) unless you have a good reason not to do so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First things first: using `unsafe` here is **completely unnecessary** and I would say actively malicious if I saw it in any real code. Don't use `unsafe` for "fun".

Here's a completely safe implementation of the function which walks *backwards* to construct the new tail of the list to add:

```
fn add_l(&mut self, l: &[i32]) {
    let mut tail = None;

    for &val in l.iter().rev() {
        let next = tail.take();
        tail = Some(Box::new(ListNode { val, next }));
    }

    self.next = tail;
}
```

And one that goes forwards, but requires an `unwrap`:

```
fn add_l(&mut self, l: &[i32]) {
    let mut head = self;

    for &val in l {
        head.next = Some(Box::new(ListNode::new(val)));
        head = { head }.next.as_mut().unwrap();
    }
}
```

If you **had** to do it in the forwards direction and **had** to avoid the `unwrap`, then *maybe* you could use `unsafe`. Every single `unsafe` block should contain a wealth of comments explaining how the code is safe and doesn't break the guarantees that you need to uphold.

```
fn add_l(&mut self, l: &[i32]) {
    let mut head = self;

    for &val in l {
        unsafe {
            // Boxing a value gives it a stable address.
            let mut node = Box::new(ListNode::new(val));

            // So long as this raw pointer doesn't escape this block, 
            // we don't need to worry about its lifetime as it should 
            // outlive what we need.
            let node_raw = &mut node as &mut ListNode as *mut ListNode;

            head.next = Some(node);

            // Now that we've moved the `Box` into its final place,
            // we throw away the reference to head to avoid mutable 
            // aliasing
            head = &mut *node_raw;
        }
    }
}
```

See also:

- [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec) or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423)
- [Cannot obtain a mutable reference when iterating a recursive structure: cannot borrow as mutable more than once at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37986640/155423)

Comment: rust newbie question: what are the "{}" around "head" in the code `head = { head }.next.as_mut().unwrap();` for?

Comment: @bayinamy follow the second link in the see also section. It may not be needed as of Rust 2018 though.

Comment: @Shepmaster thx, but unfortunately, it still needed in Rust 2018, version 1.31.1

Answer (score 3):

You have a number of issues here, none of which relate to copying a pointer.

I see what you're trying to do, but you're seeing 'undefined behavior' in action, not a failure to copy the pointer value.

First of all, this:

```
temp_b.next.unwrap()
```

Unwrap does not leave the object behind; it consumes it. Every iteration through, you will be setting the value of `next` to nothing as you call `unwrap`.

Secondly, on the first iteration through your loop, you convert the original pointer into a box:

```
let mut p: *mut ListNode = self as *mut ListNode;
// ... p is not reassigned before calling the next statement
Box::from_raw(p);
```

As a result, you're dropping (free'ing) the root object a when you consume temp_b.

This won't immediately trigger a crash, but it means you've now effectively corrupted the stack. Everything past this point is undefined behavior.

Look at the output when you trace your actual pointer values:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct ListNode {
    val: String,
    next: Option<Box<ListNode>>,
}

impl ListNode {
    fn new(i: &str) -> Self {
        ListNode { val: format!("{:?}", i), next: None }
    }

    fn add_l(&mut self, l: &Vec<&str>) {
        let mut p: *mut ListNode = self as *mut ListNode;
        println!("self -> {:?}", self as *mut ListNode);
        for i in l {
            unsafe {
                (*p).next = Some(Box::new(ListNode::new(*i)));
                let temp_b = Box::from_raw(p);
                println!("{:?} -> {:?}", p, temp_b);
                p = Box::into_raw(temp_b.next.unwrap());
                println!("next p -> {:?}", p);
            };

        }
        println!("self -> {:?}", self as *mut ListNode);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = ListNode::new("1");
    a.add_l(&vec!["2", "3", "4", "5"]);
    println!("self -> {:?}", &mut a as *mut ListNode);
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

...

```
self -> 0x7ffdc10a90f0
0x7ffdc10a90f0 -> ListNode { val: "\"1\"", next: Some(ListNode { val: "\"2\"", next: None }) }
next p -> 0x7fdde801f060
0x7fdde801f060 -> ListNode { val: "\"2\"", next: Some(ListNode { val: "\"3\"", next: None }) }
next p -> 0x7ffdc10a90f0
0x7ffdc10a90f0 -> ListNode { val: "\"3\"", next: Some(ListNode { val: "\"4\"", next: None }) }
next p -> 0x7fdde801f060
0x7fdde801f060 -> ListNode { val: "\"4\"", next: Some(ListNode { val: "\"5\"", next: None }) }
next p -> 0x7ffdc10a90f0 <---- Whhhaaaat! You've been reallocated!
self -> 0x7ffdc10a90f0
self -> 0x7ffdc10a90f0
ListNode { val: "\"5\"", next: None }
```

So... this is why using `unsafe` is unsafe.

You can't do what you want to do without using raw pointers all the way; I recommend you look at `Rc` for what you're trying to do.