# Linked list in Rust with nodes owned by HashMap

Tags: rust, linked-list, borrow-checker

I am trying to construct a bunch of linked-list data-structure in Rust, but different than other examples I've seen, I'd like the actual nodes to be owned by a `HashMap`. It seems like if a `HashMap` owns the nodes, then lifetimes shouldn't be an issue and this should allow me to reference the next element in my list by `Option<&List>` rather than `Box<List>` (as done in [Cannot obtain a mutable reference when iterating a recursive structure: cannot borrow as mutable more than once at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986640/cannot-obtain-a-mutable-reference-when-iterating-a-recursive-structure-cannot-b) ). However, I am getting mutable/immutable borrow errors.

My minimal example is:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct List<'a> {
    data: i32,
    child: Option<&'a List<'a>>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut map = HashMap::<i32, List>::new();

    let data = vec![(1, None), (2, Some(1))];

    for (data, child) in data.iter() {
        println!("Inserting {:?} with child {:?}", data, child);
        let new_node = map.entry(*data).or_insert(List {
            data: *data,
            child: None,
        });
        match child {
            Some(child_data) => {
                map.get(child_data).map(|child_node| {
                    new_node.child = Some(child_node);
                });
            }
            None => {}
        }
    }

    println!("Data: {:?}", map);
}
```

Which gives the error

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `map` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:16:24
   |
16 |         let new_node = map.entry(*data).or_insert(List {
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
...
22 |                 map.get(child_data).map(|child_node| {
   |                 --- immutable borrow occurs here

error[E0502]: cannot borrow `map` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:22:17
   |
16 |         let new_node = map.entry(*data).or_insert(List {
   |                        --- mutable borrow occurs here
...
22 |                 map.get(child_data).map(|child_node| {
   |                 ^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
23 |                     new_node.child = Some(child_node);
   |                     -------- mutable borrow later captured here by closure
```

My question is, is this error a result of me not setting up the `List` struct correctly, a result of the way I am using `HashMap`, and how can I fix it?

Comment: The error is correct. If you have a node that points to itself (e.g. `(1, Some(1)`), then `new_node` and `map.get(...)` will alias.

Comment: Also, `HashMap` is backed by a growable array. Every time the hashtable fills up, it will reallocate and invalidate all existing references. So what you're doing is fundamentally impossible.

Comment: So I still need to `Box` things and send both `List` and `HashMap` the boxed type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is correct:

1. If you have a node that refers to itself (e.g. `(1, Some(1))`), then `new_node` and `child_node` will point to the same value. This is illegal as `new_node` is a mutable (read: exclusive) reference.
2. `HashMap`, like `Vec`, is backed by an array. When the `HashMap` fills up, it will reallocate this array, invalidating all existing references.
3. `HashMap` lets you delete entries. This will cause dangling pointers if a deleted entry is referenced elsewhere.

Here are a few solutions to this problem:

- Store the index instead. This is the simplest solution, and is recommended most of the time.

  ```rust
  struct List {
    data: i32,
    child: Option<i32>,
  }
  ```
- Use an append-only collection like [`elsa::FrozenMap`](https://docs.rs/elsa/1.3.2/elsa/map/struct.FrozenMap.html). This only solves problem 3, but `Box` and `Cell` should handle the rest:

  ```rust
  use elsa::FrozenMap;

  struct List<'a> {
    data: i32,
    child: Cell<Option<&'a List<'a>>>,
  }

  fn main() {
    let map = FrozenMap::<i32, Box<List>>::new();

    // ...
  }
  ```